# Simple Form + Select2: can't type dynamic tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, jquery-select2, simple-form

I am using Rails 6 with simple form & Select2.

I have an Item model with array field "tags".
I want to add tags to items using Select2 dynamic option creation.

Problem is that **I cannot type** in the Select2 field. Other functions work fine.

It looks like input field is not available, so I cannot add new one. I can only select tags from list:

[image: tags with select2]

I would like it to work like in this example:

[Dynamic option creation](https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

In my form:

```
  = f.input :tags, collection: @items.distinct('tags'),
    input_html: { class: 'select-tags', multiple: true }, include_hidden: false

javascript:
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    $(".select-tags").select2({
        tags: true
    });
    console.log($(".select-tags"))
  });
```

Console output:

```
[Log] jQuery [<select id="item_tags">] (1) (new, line 88)

<select class="form-control select optional select-tags select2-hidden-accessible" multiple name="item[tags][]" id="item_tags" data-select2-id="item_tags" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">. 
  <option value="tag_1">tag_1</option>
  <option value="tag_2">tag_2</option>
  <option value="tag_3">tag_3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you could try `select_tag` instead

Comment: Unfortunately not helped ;/

Comment: i guess your javascript has not been applied yet, could you check on your web console and show logs if any ?

Comment: you could put console.log on `turbolinks:load` callback to make sure jquery is loaded, also `select2` is setup and so on ...

Comment: Updated with the output. Turbolink are loading ok, select is found...

Comment: so what you mean `I cannot type` ? your tags selections show as a select box and there's no input field ?

Comment: It means that input look like disabled for typing, but is available for select tags from list. By typing I would like to create new ones. I put screenshot above.